# Solve series with two constants and opposite exponents

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, constants

How can I find the general formula for the sum of this series?

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n a^ib^{n-i}
$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are unrelated constants?

I don't think you can split it into 
$
\sum_{i=0}^n a^i
$
and $
\sum_{i=0}^n b^{n-i}
$ right?

Is there a way to simplify this?  I'm not sure how to start this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you encountered geometric series before?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the sum can be rearranged as

$$b^n \sum_{i = 0}^n \left(\frac a b\right)^i$$

which is now in the form of an [explicitly computable geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Comment: Ahh, I'm hitting myself. I should have figured that out.  Thanks!